# ViewBag dropdown from aspnetusers table is not saving to database on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a list of items from a dropdown list created from a custom property in the "ASP.NET Identity", "aspnetusers" table named "FullName".  My goal is to select the name from the dropdown list and have the fullname and Id saved in my "Application" table creating a one-to-many relationship.  The dropdown list is populating with the names, but isn't saving them into my application table.

Model:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
public class Application
{

    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    *****Asp.net identity application user class that I have a custom full name property in*****

public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

   }
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.LoanOfficer = new SelectList(db.Users,"Id","FullName");
        return View();
    }

     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Id,FullName,FirstName,LastName")] Application application)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.LoanOfficer = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName", application.ApplicationUser);

            db.Applications.Add(application);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Thanks");
        }


        return View(application);
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("LoanOfficer", "Select Loan Officer")
```

Comment: You only seem to be binding to "Id,FullName,FirstName,LastName", how are you gewtting the selected value from the view for the "ApplicationUser" as you don't seen to be binding to anything that stores this value.

Comment: where is `db` declared?

Comment: I just have a @HtmlDropDownList in my view.  Added it above.

Comment: I have it declared right above my Index action method

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.  Mind providing an example? "Id" and "FullName" are from the aspnetusers table.

Answer (score 2):

Your model does not have a property named `LoanOfficer` so it cant be bound. If you inspect `Request.Form` you will see the `ID` value of the selected `User` so you would then need to manually add that to `Application` before saving it. But you have a lot of issues with your code including the way you are using `@Html.DropDownList()`, the pointless use of `[Bind(Include="...")]` (your listing all 3 properties but they are all bound by default anyway, and you have included "FullName" which is not even a property of the model), and your recreating the `SelectList` if the model is valid (which is pointless since you immediately redirect, but not creating it if you return the view - which means nothing will be shown in the dropdownlist)

Create a view model to represent what you want to display and edit

```
public class ApplicationVM
{
  [Required]
  [DisplayName("First Name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [DisplayName("Last Name")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [DisplayName("Loan officer")]
  public int? LoanOfficer { get; set; } 
  public SelectList LoanOfficerList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ApplicationVM model = new ApplicationVM();
  model.LoanOfficerList = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName");
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ApplicationVM model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    model.LoanOfficerList = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName");
    return View(model);
  }
  // Initialize new Application, set properties from the view model, save and redirect
}
```

View

```
@model ApplicationVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  // controls for FirstName and LastName properties
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoanOfficer)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LoanOfficer, Model.LoanOfficerList, "--Please select--")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoanOfficer)
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```